# Calculate the Riemann Stieltjes integral

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

This is not a homework question.  It is a past exam question and I would appreciate some step by step help, as I never understood this concept in class.

Let $\alpha(t) = n^2$ for $t\in[n,n+1).$  Calculate the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $$\int_0^4x^2d\alpha(x)$$ from the definition.

Comment: I'm getting an answer of 170, but don't know if what I'm trying to do is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by $\alpha(t)=n^2$ ? Is $\alpha(t)$ a constant?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a step function, so I think I can just evaluate the integral around the jumps

Comment: http://math2.eku.edu/jones/analysis_e_084.pdf Theorem 86 should be helpful, and I got $58$, still need to check

Answer (score 5):

The Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^b f(x) dg(x)$ is the limit as the step size tends to zero of $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(c_i)(g(x_{i+1})-g(x_i))$ for $a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b$ where $c_i$ is between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$.

$\alpha(x_{i+1})-\alpha(x_i)$ is $0$ unless $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ straddle the boundary between integers, which in the limit happens at $1,2,3$.

$\int_0^4 x^2 \mathrm{d}\alpha(x)=1^2(1^2-0^2)+2^2(2^2-1^2)+3^2(3^2-2^2)=58$

Comment: Why do you not have to take 4 into account?  This is how I worked the problem but included $4^2(4^2-3^2)$

Comment: The $x_i$ go up to $4$. To straddle $4$ some $x_i$ would have to go over it.